# FFmpeg ignores some HTTP options when using the PUT method

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, mediastore, mpeg-dash

I am using FFmpeg to create a CMAF stream and I upload it to an **AWS** resource (AWS MediaStore) using the `PUT` method of FFMpeg. 
I need to pass the `Content-Type` header when uploading manifests & segments.
I have 3 type of files:

`application/x-mpegURL` : m3u8 manifest

`application/dash+xml` : mpd manifest

`video/mp4` : video segments

Currently, all the types are set to `Binary - octet-stream` in the **AWS** resource (AWS MediaStore).
As I will upload a huge number of files, I can't use AWS Lambda functions to set the correct content type after a file as been uploaded.

### FFmpeg upload logs

```sh
[https @ 0x555fe7a7d1c0] Opening 'https://XXXX.YYYY.amazonaws.com/chunk-stream0-00001.mp4' for writing
[https @ 0x555fe7a7d0c0] request: PUT /chunk-stream0-00001.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
User-Agent: Lavf/58.28.100
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: XXXXX.YYYY.amazonaws.com
Icy-MetaData: 1
```

### My tries

I tried static builds & master branch of FFMpeg.
I tried different ways to pass the content type, without success :

`-mime_type 1 -headers "Content-type: video/mp4\r\n"`

`-mime_type "video/mp4,application/dash+xml,application/x-mpegURL"`

`-content_type application/dash+xml`

`-multiple_requests 1  -headers "a:b" -icy 0`

### Upload command :

```sh
./ffmpeg -re -i ~/videos/BigBuckBunny.mp4 -loglevel debug \
  -map 0 -map 0 -map 0 -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency \
  -b:v:0 2000k -s:v:0 1280x720 -profile:v:0 high -b:v:1 1500k -s:v:1 640x340  -profile:v:1 main -b:v:2 500k -s:v:2 320x170  -profile:v:2 baseline -bf 1 \
 -keyint_min 24 -g 24 -sc_threshold 0 -b_strategy 0 -ar:a:1 22050 -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 -window_size 5 \
 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" -hls_playlist 1 -seg_duration 3 -streaming 1 \
 -strict experimental -lhls 1 -remove_at_exit 0 -master_m3u8_publish_rate 3 \
 -f dash -method PUT -http_persistent 1  https://example.com/manifest.mpd
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

*Reference:*
https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#http

Comment: If I make a patch for ffmpeg - I'd set the mime type automatically according to the content. video/mp4 for video, audio/m4 for audio etc. Are you interested in setting the mine correctly based the asset pushed to AWS?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I would like to pass the `Content-Type` & custom AWS headers. Those custom headers are : `x-amz-storage-class` and `x-amz-upload-availability` . Passing mime type automatically would be great. In my understanding, manifest should have the `STANDARD` storage class and video segments should have the `STREAMING`storage class.  Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediastore/latest/apireference/API_objstore_PutObject.html

Comment: (late to the party) more recent ffmpeg parameter should work to provide a custom headers `-http_opts "headers='x-amz-upload-availability:STREAMING'" `

Comment: @Whome thanks a lot for the info ! I was able to see the request headers in the ffmpeg debug logs.